# Can not listen to .wav audio file?

Tags: java, audio, wav, endianness

I am creating a client server program where the client sends a string and as soon as server receives the string it plays a `.wav` file. Instead of playing the `.wav` file the server shows this error:

```
javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format PCM_SIGNED 48000.0 Hz, 24 bit, stereo, 6 bytes/frame, little-endian not supported.
```

Here's the code:

```
try {
  AudioInputStream audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("N.wav"));
  Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
  clip.open(audio);
  clip.start();
} catch(UnsupportedAudioFileException uae) {
  System.out.println(uae);
} catch(IOException ioe) {
  System.out.println(ioe);
} catch(LineUnavailableException lua) {
  System.out.println(lua);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your relative pathing is probably not where you expect it to be. Try using an absolute path for `N.wav` and see if it works. (i.e. `/home/navjosh/Sounds/N.wav` or `C:\Users\navjosh\Documents\N.wav` etc.

Comment: URL soundFile =new URL("C:\Users\naval\N.wav");
         AudioInputStream audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(soundFile));

Comment: You need to do \\  because \ has meaning in Java `String`s. To correctly place the \ character in a Java `String`,  use \\.

Comment: I tried C:\\Users\\naval\\N.wav and it worked but the same error persisted.javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format PCM_SIGNED 48000.0 Hz, 24 bit, stereo, 6 bytes/frame, little-endian not supported.